# Past tense of "mind" in "mind your own business"

Tags: past-tense

With a saying such as *keep it to myself* you can say the past tense as *kept it to myself*.

How about *mind my own business*? Should it be *minded my own business*, *mound my own business* or something else?

Answer (score 6):

Often you hear 'mind my own business' in the past continuous:

> I was minding my own business when ...

'Minded my own business' is seldom used, but you could say something like:

> From that point on, I minded my own business.

'Mound' is not used ... unless you are talking about the noun for a small hill or pile ;)